# how to delete specific characters in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, special-characters, gsub

There is already created record, like

```
Company &quot;Life&quot;
```

How to make this record to the species

```
сompany-life
```

I used parameterize, but it turns:

```
company-quot-life-quot
```

As I understand, `.gsub("&quot;", "")` is not suitable for implementation, since to create too large list of exceptions

Is there may be a way to make record in raw format? (to parameterize  later)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using regular expression? So just write a regex to generate any adjusted string you want.

Comment: Your problem is that you're storing encoded entities in your database. This is a very poor implementation. You should be storing the *real data*, and HTML-encoding it only when it goes from your app into a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-Rails approach:

```
require 'cgi'

str = 'Company &quot;Life&quot;'

puts CGI.unescape_html(str).gsub(/"/, '').gsub(/\s+/, '-').downcase

# => company-life
```

And a pure regex solution:

```
puts str.gsub(/&\w+;/, '').gsub(/\s+/, '-').downcase
# => company-life
```

And if you are inside Rails(thanks to @nzifnab):

```
str.gsub(/&\w+;/, '').parameterize
```

Comment: If you don't want to have to use `gsub` in that first example change it to `CGI.unescape_html(str).parameterize`

Comment: Why not `str.gsub(/&\w+;/, '').parameterize`

Comment: as is said it is a "non-Rails approach" :)

Comment: Ya but my version is the best of both worlds ;)  Unescapes the html and makes it friendly for use in url's without having to chain a million gsubs for every kind of special character you might not want to show up

Comment: @skalee, what do you mean?

Comment: @silvu — z`CGI.unescape_html` won't handle entity like `&copy;` properly. Also the latter, regexp-based solutions, will change `abc&mdash;def` into `abcdef`, instead of `abc-def`.  Modified third one — `str.gsub(/&\w+;/, '-').parameterize` — would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As @meager said, you shouldn't be storing the html-encoded entities in the database to begin with, how did it get in there with `&quot;`?  Theoretically this would work:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :unescape_entities

  private
  def unescape_entities
    self.name = CGI.unescape_html(name)
  end
end
```

But I'm still curious how `name` would be getting there in the first place with html entities in it.  What's your action/form look like?

Comment: This won't necessarily decode of all your entities. `CGI.unescape_html("&quot;&reg;") #=> "\"&reg;"`

Comment: Ive made this a  necessity, because I introduced globalize3+friendly_id,  and I want to translate all old records to current version with friendly slugs in migration file.

Answer (score -1):

```
"Company &quot;Life&quot;".html_safe.parameterize
```

Comment: This is completely wrong; `.html_safe` doesn't turn `&quot;` into a quotation mark. It simply prevents `&quot;` from being turned into `&quot;quot;`

Comment: No, this answer was more symbolic. Within ActionView runtime it will be the best decision. If not, use Regexp /&#?\w+;/.

Comment: @ValeryKvon No, even within ActionView runtime, it will still not work. This is completely incorrect. This is *not the purpose* of `.html_safe.`

Comment: Ok, you're right, sorry :) I've forget i'm using extended year ago ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer, so it can. Native Rails' - is not.

Answer (score -1):

```
"Company &quot;Life&quot;".gsub(/&[^;]+;/, "-").parameterize.downcase
# => "company-life"
```

Firstly, gsub gets rid of html entities, then parameterize gets rid from all but Ascii alphanumeric (and replaces them with dash), then downcase.  Note that "_" will be preserved too, if you don't like them, another `gsub('_', '-')` is needed.

Comment: Why not `.gsub(/&[^;]*;/, "")`.parameterize`?

Comment: Why are you obsessed with using a regex?  `CGI` gives you the correct behavior for free without having to re-invent the wheel and inevitably missing something important.

Comment: @nzifnab – I was not aware that it handles HTML escaping too.

Comment: CGI doesn't handle decoding html entities very well. It will decode `&quot;` but it leaves others, like `&trade;` alone. So it only partially handles the entities.

Comment: @meagar — yeah, parameterize gives better results since it transliterates string.